# How to set proxy from command line Windows 7

Tags: powershell, command-line, proxy, windows-7-x64

I need to set a proxy using command line in windows .

Have you any idea about the commands to execute ?

Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 7):

For me neither the above in the previous answer neither what suggested [here](http://www.zerrouki.com/working-behind-a-proxy/)(that is quite the same, only explained a bit better).

What instead has worked so far, and only for the session, is this command:

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).Proxy.Credentials =  
[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

as from really well explained [here](https://martin.hoppenheit.info/blog/2015/using-powershell-behind-proxy/)

Then I was able to retrieve web content as for example:

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://example.org
```

Comment: how do you run this for each new powershell instance??

Comment: @gianni, what you mean exactly? At same time? I guess you can write a powershell script in the integrated env, as I guess still exist. Is been a while since I don't use powershell now.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is a possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/419696/in-windows-7-how-to-change-proxy-settings-from-command-line

There is a command named set proxy. See the following:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy.domain.com:port
```

Using netsh

```
netsh winhttp set proxy  [proxy server address:port number] [bypass list]
```

Also see the following:

http://www.ehow.com/how_6887864_do-proxy-settings-command-prompt_.html

https://superuser.com/questions/337685/how-do-i-change-the-windows7-lan-proxy-config-from-the-command-line