# How to build Ghidra from source code in China?

Tags: powershell, github, proxy, ghidra

Here is Ghidra build steps:
https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra#build
When I run this command:

```
gradle -I gradle/support/fetchDependencies.gradle init
```

The error:

```
URL: https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/releases/download/v2.1/dex2jar-2.1.zip
   Connecting...
   Connection error! java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
   Connecting (2/3)...
```

I have proxy and try to set proxy like this, but same error.

```
$env:HTTP_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:10809"
$env:HTTPS_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:10809"
```

Is there another valid method to set powershell proxy?

Comment: Not sure, if this is a duplicate, but did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36571883/how-to-set-proxy-from-command-line-windows-7?

Answer (score 0):

It's "gradle"!
Edit gradle.properties, add these lines:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=10809
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=10809
```

Then I can download by proxy.